# Was 1 considered a number under older meanings of number?

Tags: numbers

I have read a popular account somewhere that contended that 1 did not used to be considered a number, with common sentences like "He has a number of friends in England." or some such as evidence. Is this true

Comment: This is a very good question about semantics and semantic shift. Why the votes to close?

Comment: Please expand your question.   Which language communities are you talking about?    What historical or prehistoric period are we talking about?  What examples can you cite?    This is a cool question, but it needs more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that “a number of friends” means “two or more friends”, though one could be pedantic and insist that “one” and “zero” are also numbers.

As a matter of fact, the bible of ancient and mediaeval mathematics, Euclid’s “Elements”, defines “number” in book VII, definition 2 with the words: “A number is the multitude composed of units” ( ̓Αριθμὸς δὲ τὸ ἐκ μονάδων συγκείμενον πλῆθος), which clearly means that the “unit” (one) is not a number.

It remained thus for a long time in English too. The Oxford English Dictionary has this quotation from a 14th-century English translation of a Latin book: “Þe secounde odde noumbre [L. numerus impar], þat is, þe nombre of fyue”. In other words, the first odd number is not 1 but 3; the second odd number is thus 5.

In modern mathematics, beginning with Descartes, “number” has been redefined to include not only “one”, but also “zero”, and then eventually the negative numbers, fractions, irrational numbers, imaginary numbers etc., etc.

We discussed this also here: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5326/why-did-the-ancient-greek-count-1-in-case-of-perfect-numbers-but-not-otherwise/5332#5332